# Is there a way of creating an element and sending it to another function that "appendChild"?

Tags: javascript, appendchild, createelement

I have made a variable that is a function. This function is creating an Element, applies style and returns the variable within the function.

I later have a for-loop that has a "if" that wants to add that element to an already existing div by using "appendChild", but I do not manage to make it work.

Any suggestions?

```
var wall = function () {

    var tmp_wall = document.createElement('div');

    document.getElementById("g_world").appendChild(tmp_wall);
}

var ground = function () {

    var tmp_ground = document.createElement('div');

    document.getElementById("g_world").appendChild(tmp_ground);
}

// *****************************************************************

var world = [
    [1,1],
    [2,2],
];

function drawWorld () {

    for(var y = 0; y < world.length; y++) {

        for(var x = 0; x < world[y]; x++) {

            if(world[y][x] === 1) {
                wall();
            }
            else if (world[y][x] === 2) {
                ground();
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('g_world').innerHTML += '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: None of the code after `return tmp_wall;` ever runs. Is that supposed to be the end of the function?

Comment: Your code isn't going to do much; it returns `tmp_wall` and doesn't run any of the code after that. Please provide a [mcve]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) do so.

Comment: Where do you call the `wall()` function?

Comment: See `document.getElementById('g_world') += document.g_world.appendChild(wall);` I *think* you are trying to call your `wall` function there, but you have to use `wall()`.

Comment: your code snippet is incomplete. Please post full code snippet.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a bit strange:

```
document.getElementById('g_world') += document.body.appendChild(ground);
```

`appendChild` works like this:

```
document.getElementById('g_world').appendChild(ground());
```

Can you try and check if that works?

Also, your script won't continue after the return statement. Maybe there are some semicolons missing in your example code?

EDIT:
Your problem is in the second for-loop. You forgot to add `.length`, like this:

```
for(var x = 0; x < world[y].length; x++) {
```

Comment: I updated the text to make it easier to understand what I want to achieve!

EDIT: No, it didn't work out.

Comment: The wall/ground elements are not being added to the world? Are there any JavaScript errors in your browser console?

Comment: No, I tried rewriting the code. I'll update it, but no result.

Comment: Try `wall()` and `ground()`. Executing the function returns the element. I updated my answer.

Comment: I've tried both now. Having the "document.getElementById().appendChild()" in the function and executing it by simply stating "wall()" in the "if", but nothing seem to work.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this? Then I can take a better look at what's going wrong

Comment: Found your problem. It was in the second for-loop. Updated it in the answer above.

Comment: Thank you!! God dammit, have been staring myself blind.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed a couple of o things on your code and it may or not be helpful.

The first point is that you are returning `return tmp_wall` what makes your code does not run after that point.

the second point is that you have a closure inside your code and you should invoke it to properly use it.

The third point would be you are not trying to append the element that you have created tmp_wal.

You cannot add the same element to the dom multiple times and work around it would be to use [cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) or instead create new elements for each iteration on your for().

The closure `drawWorld`also missing some close tags.

I would approach it a little different using only JS, However, I decided to change as little as possible to give you the grid you want.

I would do the following:

```
var wall = function() {
//   var tmp_wall = document.createElement("div");

//   tmp_wall.style.width = 50 + "px";
//   tmp_wall.style.height = 50 + "px";
//   tmp_wall.style.backgroundColor = "green";
//   tmp_wall.className = "wall";

  var world = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
  ];

  const gWorldElement = document.getElementById("g_world");

  function drawWorldContainer() {
    for (let i = 0; i < world.length; i++) {
      const newElementI = document.createElement("div");
      gWorldElement.appendChild(newElementI);
      for (let j = 0; j < world[i].length; j++) {
        const newElementJ = document.createElement("div");
        gWorldElement.children[i].appendChild(newElementJ);
        newElementJ.innerText = world[i][j];
      }
    }
  }

  drawWorldContainer();
};

wall();
```

**If you set the `g_world` element as flex**, as a result, you will have a **grid layout** with div containers and other divs holding the value.

Then you can create another check such `if(world[i][j] === 1)`that checks for the value and add the classNames accordingly or change the style tag of the element.

I hope I didn't change that much your code and you still be able to work out your solution, if you have any questions please let me know.